# JavaScript destructure object properties inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I've an looping an array of object

```js
const group = [
    {
        "name": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "10007017",
                "url": "http://www.aol.com",
                "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 1,
                "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                        "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
            },
            {
                "id": "10007016",
                "url": "http://msn.com",
                "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 1,
                "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                        "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
        "values": [
            {
                "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 0,
                "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                        "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
            },
            {
                "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 0,
                "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                        "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
            }
        ]
    }
]
      for (const bfaObj of group) {
        for (const mappedObj of bfaObj.values) {
          if (
            mappedObj.requestSentStatus === null ||
            mappedObj.requestSentStatus === undefined
          ) {
            mappedObj.errMsg = 'somemessage 1';
          } else if (mappedObj.requestSentStatus === 0) {
            mappedObj.errMsg = 'somemessage 2';
          } else if (mappedObj.requestSentStatus === 1) {
            if (
              mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === null ||
              mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === undefined
            ) {
              mappedObj.errMsg = 'somemessage 3';
            } else if (mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === 0) {
              mappedObj.errMsg = 'somemessage 4';
            } else {
              mappedObj.errMsg = '';
            }
          }
          delete mappedObj.requestSentMessage;
          delete mappedObj.requestSentStatus;
          delete mappedObj.responseReceivedMessage;
          delete mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus;
        }
        }
        console.log(group)
```

Hi I've an for loop looping over arrays of object

I want to delete this objects using object destructuring instead of delete keyword, not sure how this works I tried it but it didn't actually work, also how can we optimize this piece of code instead of using nested loops.

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Right now it's just a bunch of errors because the values you're working with are not declared. ② Please [edit] to ensure that you're asking a single question and not multiple; the "also if we optimize" part at the end looks like a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, I still see errors in my IDE unrelated to what you're asking (e.g., what's `errMsg`), so the example isn't a [mre]).  And you still seem to be asking multiple questions: "how can I use destructuring to delete things" (which, uh, you can't.  It can *withhold* things, but it doesn't delete them) and "how can I optimize this code instead of using loops".  Please [edit] to address these if you can.  I might disengage, so good luck!

Comment: Instead of adding new properties and deleting old properties, do you just want to *replace the object* with a completely new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to delete the object properties using object destructuring instead of delete keyword. You can use [`rest syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) to omit the properties you don't need.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const group = [
  {
      "name": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
      "values": [
          {
              "id": "10007017",
              "url": "http://www.aol.com",
              "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
              "requestSentStatus": 1,
              "responseReceivedStatus": 1,
              "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                      "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
          },
          {
              "id": "10007016",
              "url": "http://msn.com",
              "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
              "requestSentStatus": 1,
              "responseReceivedStatus": 1,
              "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                      "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "name": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
      "values": [
          {
              "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
              "requestSentStatus": 1,
              "responseReceivedStatus": 0,
              "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                      "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
          },
          {
              "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
              "requestSentStatus": 1,
              "responseReceivedStatus": 0,
              "requestSentMessage": "RECEIVED",
                      "responseReceivedMessage": "SUCCESS",
          }
      ]
  }
];

for (const bfaObj of group) {
  bfaObj.values = bfaObj.values.map(mappedObj => {
    const {
      requestSentMessage,
      requestSentStatus,
      responseReceivedMessage,
      responseReceivedStatus,
      ...rest
    } = mappedObj;

    let errMsg = '';

    if (requestSentStatus === null || requestSentStatus === undefined) {
      errMsg = 'somemessage 1';
    } else if (requestSentStatus === 0) {
      errMsg = 'somemessage 2';
    } else if (requestSentStatus === 1) {
      if (responseReceivedStatus === null || responseReceivedStatus === undefined) {
        errMsg = 'somemessage 3';
      } else if (responseReceivedStatus === 0) {
        errMsg = 'somemessage 4';
      }
    }

    return {
      ...rest,
      errMsg,
    };
  });
}

console.log(group);
```

Comment: It's not spread syntax but rest syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out. Yeah you are correct. I corrected the wording.